# Configuration of luminoth training/evaluation job for Google Cloud ML using voc2012

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard, google-cloud-ml

How to configure a [luminoth](https://github.com/tryolabs/luminoth) training job (on Google Cloud ML) and tensorboard? I transformed voc2012 to tfrecord format and uploaded to a bucket.
So now I want to train the default model (FasterRCNN) using the voc2012 dataset.

Which config file should I use? *sample_config.yml* or the *base_config.yml* file in the fasterrcnn directory?
How do I submit an evaluation job?

Anything to consider for the Tensorboard usage?

Comment: Your questions are fairly specific to luminoth. You should be able to run Tensorboard from a non-windows machine by pointing it to your output directory. I don't know how evaluation jobs work in Luminoth, but on CloudML Engine, the Master is often setup for doing the evaluation. You might be able to just run it as another "train" job (that doesn't actually train) on CloudML Engine.

Comment: Actually it was not yet implemented. Yesterday they commited an update supporting evaluation by: lumi cloud gc evaluate
Attention: Yet only for Ubuntu because it connects to gs:// directly

Answer (score 0):

To submit an evaluation job:

```
lumi cloud gc evaluate
```

Options:

```
--job-id TEXT               // JobId for saving models and logs. [required]   
--service-account-json TEXT // [required]   
--bucket TEXT               // Where to save models and logs.   
--split TEXT                // Dataset split to use.   
--region TEXT               // Region in which to run the job.
--scale-tier [BASIC|STANDARD_1|PREMIUM_1|BASIC_GPU|CUSTOM]   
--rebuild                   // Rebuild and upload package.   
--postfix TEXT              // Postfix for the evaluation job name.   
-h, --help                  // Show this message and exit.
```